# Brackets in input (Python)

Tags: python, input

So i want for the user to input text but I want text already in the place where they type it.
For example:(in console)

please enter something: ["They enter stuff here but brackets were already here"]
so the brackets are there and they type inside of the brackets.
Thanks for any help possible!

Comment: To implement this kind of interaction with the user, you need to use a [`curses`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/curses.html) package.

Comment: Another easy and lazy way is print "please enter something:[default value]. And if user enter nothing(empty string), treat it as default value.